# Implement an interface method that gets IEnumerable of interface or of base class as parameter

Tags: c#, generics, interface, ienumerable, implementation

[Surely a similar question was asked before multiple times, but somehow I couldn't find a good duplicate, so opening this one]

Generally:

Is it possible to implement an interface method, that gets `IEnumerable` of either interface or of base-class as type-parameter, where the implementing method `IEnumerable` uses a type-parameter of a class that implements the interface\derives from the base class?

More concretely:

- We have either:

  1. Some interface type `interface IZ` with some implementing classes:

     - `class CZ1: IZ`
     - `class CZ2: IZ`
  2. Some base-class type `class CZ` with some derived classes:

     - `class CZ1: CZ`
     - `class CZ2: CZ`
- `interface IA` defines a method with a parameter of either:

  - `IEnumerable<IZ>`, or:
  - `IEnumerable<CZ>`.
- `class CA1 : IA` wishes to implement the interface's method with `IEnumerable<CZ1>`, while `class CA2 :IA` wishes to implement the interface's method with `IEnumerable<CZ2>`.

An implementation like this throws an error:

> <class> does not implement interface member <method with IEnumerable of interface\base-class>

- What is a possible way to make this kind of implementation compile?
- Would using generic-type parameters with constraints help in any way?
- If there is no built-in way to make it work in a direct way, is there a good "design pattern" to make implementation in this "spirit" work?

**Full example:**

Types to be used as the `IEnumerable` type-parameter (using `IZ` here, but `CZ` should behave the same way):

```
interface IZ {}
class CZ1 : IZ {}
class CZ2 : IZ {}
```

Types that try to use the type parameters:

```
interface IA
{
    void Set(IEnumerable<IZ> records)
}

class CA1 : IA 
{
    public void Set(IEnumerable<CZ1> records) {}  <-- compile error
}

class CA2 : IA
{
    public void Set(IEnumerable<CZ2> records) {}  <-- compile error
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
interface IZ { }
class CZ1 : IZ { }
class CZ2 : IZ { }

interface IA<T> where T : IZ
{
    void Set(IEnumerable<T> records);
}

class CA1 : IA<CZ1>
{
    public void Set(IEnumerable<CZ1> records) { }
}
class CA2 : IA<CZ2>
{
    public void Set(IEnumerable<CZ2> records) { }
}
```